# Configure Swagger to work with DotNetNuke (DNN)

Tags: .net, swagger, dotnetnuke, swashbuckle

I am trying to use Swagger with an API I created in DotNetNuke, but I can't get it to work.

I have installed Swashbuckle and all its dependencies, but I cannot access the swagger ui endpoint. I believe that DotNetNuke is messing with the routing, and that is causing the problem.

I have a RouteMapper that is implemented like this:

```
    public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("MyAPI", "default", "{controller}/{action}", new[] { "MyAPI.Controllers" });
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how this problem can be fixed, in order to be able to access the swagger's endpoints?

Comment: Hi @Andrei, what version of DNN you're using?

Comment: Hello Cris, I am using DNN 9

Comment: @AndreiCurta did you get this to work at the end?

Comment: @ParasDaryanani I have tried the suggestions in this post but unfortunately I did not manage to get swagger to work with dnn

Answer (score 1):

Within the DNN Platform under SEO > URL Management > Expressions there is a setting `Ignore URL Regular Expression` this is a Regular Expression that tells the Friendly URL system to completely ignore the pattern.  You will need to add Swagger to this.

NOTE: This is something that in general does NOT play well with DNN, so your results might be a bit "iffy"

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried to follow your suggestion, but it did not work. I have changed the regular expression under "Do Not Use Friendly URLs Regular Expression" to `/Rss\.aspx|/api/MyAPI/swagger`. I also used the tool provided within the site settings to check if the url would get rewritten and it showed it wouldn't. I am assuming that swagger should be at `http://dnndev.me/API/MyAPI/swagger`

Comment: You actually need to add this into the "Ignore URL Regular Expression" one for this to work